# PHP and regex: Check if string follows the pattern with square brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have no experience with regular expressions whatsoever, hence my question.

I have a string which should look like this:

[1,24,2,59]

As the string can be manipulated by the user and hence changed, I want to check whether it is still following the same organization pattern, and only containing numbers,square brackets and commas.

Comment: If you don't have experience with it go get some! Of course, it is a new field of expertise and might take a day or two to get into, but it is absolutely possible.

Comment: That will be next on my list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex in `preg_match` to validate your input:

```
'/\[\d+(,\d+)*\]/'

\[ matches the character [ literally
\d+ match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as
  needed [greedy]
1st Capturing group (,\d+)*
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as 
  needed [greedy]
Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing 
  group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group 
   instead if you're not interested in the data
, matches the character , literally
\d+ match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as 
  needed [greedy]
\] matches the character ] literally
```

Comment: Thanks for a fast and very detailed response. Thanks a lot for clearing this up for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
'/^\[\d+(,\d+)*\]$/'
```

Same as the other answer, except it requires the whole string to match, otherwise a valid substring would suffice (e.g. "bla bla [1,3] bla bla")

```
'/^\[([1-9]\d+|\d)(,([1-9]\d+|\d))*\]$/'
```

Same, but numbers must have leading zeros removed, so "[12]" is OK but "[012]" is not.

```
'/^\s*\[\s*([1-9]\d+|\d)(\s*,\s*([1-9]\d+|\d))*\s*\]\s*$/'
```

Allows white spaces, e.g. " [ 1 , 12 , 12 ] " will be accepted but not "[1 2]".